# Como validar una variable en caso de que sea null c#

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo el siguiente método que utilizo en el cual obtengo una edad a través de un procedimiento en PL/SQL el cual hace una consulta, necesito validar y asignarle un valor en caso de que esa edad se encuentre vacía. El valor que le deseo asignar cuando este vació es 0,

El siguiente es el método que utilizo en **C#** para obtener la edad:

```
public static string ObtenerEdad(int pidm, int p_option)
        {
            string edad = string.Empty;

            using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(_conString))
            {
                using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("P_PRUEBA.p_edad", connection)
                {
                    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                    BindByName = true
                })
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("id", OracleDbType.Int32)
                    {
                        Value = pidm,
                        Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
                    });
                    command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("option", OracleDbType.Int32)
                    {
                        Value = 1,
                        Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
                    });
                    command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_dato", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 5)
                    {
                        Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
                    });
                    connection.Open();

                    int ejecucion = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    try
                    {
                        edad = command.Parameters["p_dato"]?.Value.ToString().Trim();                        
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        connection.Close();
                    }
                };
            }
            return edad;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias formas de resolverlo, podrias validarlo desde el parametro o desde la variable directamente.

O sea podrias usar

```
 return string.IsNullOrEmpty(edad) ? "0" : edad;
```

asi validas si esta vacia la variable.

Si es desde el parametro habria que ver si retorna un `null` o un `DBNull` como respuesta cuando no tiene dato.

```
var dato = command.Parameters["p_dato"].Value;
edad = dato == DBNull.Value ?.ToString().Trim();
```

No creo que usar el `?` con el parametro aplique si es un tipo de dato que retorne la db